# Search MultiByte Strings using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, webbrowser-control, multibyte

I am working on html documents using WebBrowser control, I need to make a utility which searches a word and highlights it in the browser. It works well if the string is in English, but for strings in other languages for example in Korean, it doesn't seem to work.

The Scenario where the below mentioned code works is-

Consider user has selected a word "Example" in the Webpage, now I need to highlight this word and all its occurences. Also I need to calculate their byteOffset (the code snippet does that only).

Now for English language the below code works fine but for languages like Korean it does not worked at all.

its not getting inside the for-each loop

```
foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(this._documentContent))
```

here _documentContent contains the webpage source as string.
occurenceNo is the no. of occurence of selected word in the document

Here's the code, strTemp contains korean string:

```
string strTemp = myRange.text;
string strExp =@">(([^<])*?)" + strTemp + "(([^<])*?)<";

int intCount =0;
Regex reg = new Regex(strExp);
Regex reg1 = new Regex(strTemp);
foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(this._documentContent))
{ 
    string strMatch = m.Value;
    foreach (Match m2 in reg.Matches(strMatch))
    { 
        intCount += 1;
        if (intCount==OccurenceNo)
        {
            int intCharOffset = m.Index + m2.Index;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding d = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
            int intByteOffset = d.GetBytes( _documentContent.Substring(1, intCharOffset)).Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: showing the actual code would probably helps ...

Comment: can you post some code. C# is unicode, so as long as your encoding is read properly, you should be able to do anything with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works for English words, but does not return any results for Korean, then I might suggest that it's a culture issue, so you might try setting the RegexOptions to CultureInvariant:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(strExp, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
Regex reg1 = new Regex(strTemp, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following RegEx code for Korean:

```
private static readonly Regex regexKorean = new Regex(@"[가-힣]");
public static bool IsKorean(this char s)
{
    return regexKorean.IsMatch(s.ToString());
}

if (someText.Any(z => z.IsKorean()))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```